# How to run j2me game to all screen resolution like andengine

Tags: java-me, andengine

I am developing a game in j2me and android . In android using andengine to develop the game and its support all screen resolution. But in j2me, need to workout for porting. Its any tool like andeninge for j2me . Any tools for j2me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndEngine gets scaling for free because it's using OpenGL. If you want scaling to work for J2ME like it does for AndEngine, you'll have to use OpenGL also. Otherwise, you'll probably need to calculate the scale yourself. Since it's not too complicated, I don't think there are any libraries made specifically for this problem.